# Sum of double value in a List using Lambda from Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I want to iterate through the list of Accounts, and sum up the Double credit amount using **Java 8 lambda feature**. Any ideas?

```
import lombok.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Account {

private Double amount;
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Boolean active;
private String companyCode;
private Long accountNumber;

    public Boolean isActiveAccount() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

I have a List of Accounts, I want to sum the credit amount using the Lambda Java 1.8 feature, how do I go about that, instead of the traditional approach that I have shown below?

```
//Lets pretend that the list has 3000 account-elements.
List<Account> accountsList = new ArrayList<>();

Double totalAmount = 0.0;

for (Account account : accountsList) {
    Double accAmountList = account.getAmount();
    if(null != accAmountList) totalAmount += accAmountList;
}
```

Comment: What did you try yourself? Suggestion: Make a stream out of the list, map to a list of double values, and sum the content of the stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a stream out of the list, map to a list of double values

```
total=accountList.stream()
.filter(account ->account!=null&& 
account.getAmount()!=null).mapToDouble(Account::getAmount)
.sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code does it:

```
accountsList.stream()
            .filter(a -> a != null && a.getAmount != null)
            .mapToDouble(Account::getAmount)
            .sum();
```

`stream()` creates the `Stream`.
`filter` makes sure that no NPE will be thrown
`mapToDouble(Account::getAmount)` *replaces* each `Account` in the `Stream` with the `Account#amount`.
`sum()` sums the values.